# Как работать с алгоритмом any_of из стандартной библиотеки?

Tags: c++

Искал на сайте и в других источниках информацию о работе c алгоритмом `any_of`, но ее очень мало.

Comment: что конкретно не ясно из [описания и примера](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/any_of/)?

Comment: Как задавать условие диапазону

Comment: какое условие и какому диапазону?

Comment: **std::array<int,7> foo = {0,1,-1,3,-3,5,-5};
if ( std::any_of(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [](int i){return i<0;}) )**

Comment: это пример по ссылке выше, что вы в нем имеете ввиду под условием и диапазоновм?

Comment: Диапазон это набор каких-нибудь значений, а условие я ставлю этому диапазону.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee396393.aspx

Comment: начало и конец задаются итераторами, в пример: foo.begin(), foo.end(), последний параметр задает предикат

Answer (score 2):

Ну, семантика - "существует хотя бы один такой элемент, что". А синтаксис - передача диапазона (где проверяем существование элемента) и предиката (какого именно элемента существование).

Например, проверка, есть ли среди чисел в векторе четное:

```
void even_check(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    if (std::any_of(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [](int i){ return i % 2 == 0; }))
    {
        std::cout << "Четное число есть\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Все числа нечетны\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,3,5,7,9};
    even_check(v);
    v.push_back(10);
    even_check(v);
}
```

Ну, и на всякий случай (вдруг вы это хотели услышать): диапазон передается как два итератора. Синтаксического сахара в духе цикла по диапазону нет. Можно написать свой вариант для всего контейнера, типа

```
template<typename Container, typename Pred>
bool any_in(const Container c, Pred p)
{
    return any_of(cbegin(c),cend(c),p);
}

void even_check(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    if (any_in(v, [](int i){ return i % 2 == 0; }))
    {
        std::cout << "Четное число есть\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Все числа нечетны\n";
    }
}
```